# Can It be possible to have private concrete method inside abstract class in Php.

Tags: php, oop

Can It be possible to have a private concrete method inside the abstract class in Php

Comment: abstract methods cannot be private. Either public or protected is okay. If you use an IDE for development, you'll see the exact reason why methods in abstract classes cannot be private

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: yes, you can.

```
abstract class Foo 
{
    private function test() {
        echo 'abstract private' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function useTest() {
        $this->test();
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {}

$x = new Bar;
$x->useTest();
```

Live example: https://3v4l.org/Efd5Q

But that private method will be visible ONLY to that abstract class. It means, that it will have to be used by some other concrete method within the abstract class (with protected of public visibility).

The child classes won't be able to call it directly.